# Representation of Shakti in Hindu Iconography

Tags: shakti, iconography

why in numerous Hindu depictions is the "shakti" of a god often depicted on the god's knees or lap?

[image]

Comment: The ones with Lakshmi massaging Vishnu’s feet/legs are not my favorite either. Tantra side of things seems to promulgate more equality re women.